# How to get transparent navigation and status bar like on Google Photos?

Tags: android, layout, transparency, translucency, google-photos

I'm currently developing a timetable app for my school and want to incorporate a Google Photos-like list view. I've searched for resources or tutorials online, but I've only stumbled across incomplete snippets of code, deprecated libraries or outdated blog posts for KitKat. Does anybody know how I could implement this in a fairly standard app that targets API 25+ (Main activity with navigation drawer and fragments as content area)?

Here are some screenshots from Google Photos:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtZLN.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Did a similar thing using the Insets-Dispatcher and ObservableScrollView libraries :)

**EDIT** *(More details):*
The ObservableScrollView library provides Views that report back the scroll motion and therefore allow you to hide UI elements at the right time. There is a good [documentation](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/blob/master/docs/quick-start/index.md) on its [Github page](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView/) for that part.

The [Insets-Dispatcher library](https://github.com/plusCubed/insets-dispatcher) is absolutely amazing. It's like fitsSystemWindows on steroids, because it allows you to specify if you want Window insets for each direction (left|top|right|bottom), for each single UI element. And all of that directly in the layouts, in XML. So you can turn off insets at the bottom and top for the root view and enable them for the top of the toolbar (so it's not below the status bar) and bottom of the e.g. ObservableListView (so the last element isn't below the on-screen keys). But if you hide the Toolbar with a slide animation, it disappears below the status bar.

Comment: Mind giving some more details on how you did this, to help people who have this issue in the future?

Comment: Edited my comment :)